# Пунктуация в предложении "А помогло знаете что?"

Tags: пунктуация

> А помогло знаете что?

Как правильно расставить знаки пунктуации в данном предложении?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что запятую отменяет не близость *знаете* к частице, а инверсия.

Потому что при прямом порядке слов запятая замечательно стояла бы (перед придаточным):

*А знаете, что помогло?*

Старый пример из учебника (думается, "наш случай"):

*Улица Кирова не скажете где?*

Объяснением непостановки знака была именно инверсия.

Comment: _Galina Avanesova: "Мне кажется, что запятую отменяет не близость **знаете** к частице, а инверсия. Потому что при прямом порядке слов..."_ === А при прямом порядке слов мы просто имеем сложноподчинённое предложение. И ни о какой близости "знаете" к частице там речи идти не может. **ВОПРОС:** а каким членом предложения является "не скажете" в приведённом в Вашем ответе предложении: _Улица Кирова **не скажете** где?_

Comment: Слава, не дразнитесь: теорию я не проходила, я - практический редактор. ))) Сказуемое, штоль? О_о

Answer (score 1):

> ***А помогло знаете что?***

Никаких дополнительных знаков препинания в этом предложении не требуется.

Ср. с примерами у **[Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm)**:

> *А нам за это **знаешь** что будет?* (близко к частице); также: *Потом зимы были **знаешь** какие!; Я нашел на столе **знаете** что?*
>   (*знаешь, знаете* в значении экспрессивно-усилительной частицы).