# Оборот (?) "я не знаю"

Tags: пунктуация

Какая здесь пунктуация?

> А Семён, я, кстати, не знаю, почему туда пошёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение с инверсией, стиль разговорный: **А Семён я, кстати, не знаю, почему туда пошёл.**

Сравнить (прямой порядок слов): **А я, кстати, не знаю, почему Семен туда пошёл.**

У Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

3. Если главная часть сложноподчиненного предложения находится внутри придаточной (в разговорном стиле речи), то запятая обычно ставится только после главной части (а перед ней не ставится); ср.: **Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался… (Г.) — Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался хозяйством;**

Answer (score 6):

Нет такого "оборота" в природе.

При прямом порядке слов предложение выглядело бы так:

*А я, кстати, не знаю, почему Семён туда пошёл.*

*Я* - подлежащее, *не знаю* - сказуемое; *кстати* - вводное.

В придаточном, присоединённом союзным словом *почему,* подлежащее - *Семен,* сказуемое - *пошёл*, *туда* - обстоятельство.

Когда придаточное перемешано с главным, знаки другие, классический пример: *Улица Чехова не знаете где?*

В Вашем предложении следует отказаться от запятой после "Семён", иначе это выглядит как обращение.

***А Семён я, кстати, не знаю, почему туда пошёл.***

---

См. также ответы о знаках при инверсии [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429564/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8?rq=1).

---

> [Розенталь, § 107](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect107)
>
> Примечание 1. Если главное предложение находится внутри придаточного
>   (в разговорном стиле речи), то запятая обычно ставится только после
>   главного предложения, например: Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он
>   занимался… (Гоголь) (ср.: Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался
>   хозяйством).

Там же примечания 2 и 3 ещё интереснее, но не вполне относятся к вопросу.